xRDP sound redirection error
I installed the xrdp in the hyper V virtual machine with Ubuntu 20.04 OS ... But when I tried to run the command ./xrdp-installer-1.5.2.sh -s to enable sound redirect, I got error:
Skipping unpack of already unpacked source in pulseaudio-15.99.1+dfsg1

|-| Compile pulseaudio sources files..

sudo: meson: command not found

|-| Compiling and building xRDP Sound modules...

./xrdp-installer-1.5.2.sh: line 947: git: command not found

./xrdp-installer-1.5.2.sh: line 952: cd: pulseaudio-module-xrdp: No such file or directory

./xrdp-installer-1.5.2.sh: line 953: ./bootstrap: No such file or directory

./xrdp-installer-1.5.2.sh: line 954: ./configure: No such file or directory

make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.

make: *** No rule to make target 'install'. Stop.

!---------------------------------------------!

! Error while Executing compilation !

! Sound Redirection failed... !

! The Script is exiting.... !

!---------------------------------------------!

How do I fix it?
